# Angular 9 / Angular Material - formArrayName in formArrayName

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, formarray

I use Angular Material in my project and I have this form:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({    
    addresses: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    contactPersons: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

addresses looks like this:

```
let address = this.formBuilder.group({
  address: this.formBuilder.group({
    street: ['Street Number 1', [Validators.minLength(2)]],
    ...
  }),
  contactPersons: contactPersonsArray
});
```

This means that I have **contactPersons** at two different places.
My question now would be how to access **contactPersons** in **address**?

I have tried this:

```
<div formArrayName="addresses">
    <div *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; index as i" [formGroup]="address">
         <div formArrayName="address.contactPersons"> // address.contactPersons does not work
               Amount of contact persons {{address.contactPersons.length}}: 
         </div>
         <div formArrayName="contactPersons"> // I also tried this but here contactPersons from outer address is taken
```

**[EDIT]**
I have solved my problem, the solution to acces contactPersons within addresses is

```
form.controls.addresses.controls[i].controls.contactPersons.controls
```

Why it is so complicated to access objects/arrays with Angular Material is a mystery to me - maybe I have a worse overview.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: I changed addressesWithProducts to addresses - now it should be looking better to understand